# On ec2, sudo gem update --system doesn't work, says command not found

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

The command works if I don't prefix 'sudo', but then I get a permission error.

gem update --system

And if I use sudo it says the command is not found

sudo gem update --system

I'm on ec2, got into the server via SSH.

What do I do?  From what I understand there is no pwd for sudo, and root is locked out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a current working directory for sudo, and there is also a PATH.  I would recommend running `which gem` as a user, and then run `echo $PATH` as root (via `sudo`).  If the path given by the first command isn't in the PATH given by the second, there's your problem, so just add it.

My guess is you're running some sort of user-centric rvm installation; the moment you do that, all bets are off as to the sane working of your system, vis a vis 99.9% of examples on the web.  You need to learn a whole new way of working with your ruby installation.

Comment: no i'm not running rvm actually.

Comment: which gem: /opt/ruby/bin/gem
sudo echo $PATH: /opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games   can you explain what I should be doing? adding /opt/ruby/bin/gem to my path?

Comment: How in the name of flying furballs did `gem` end up in `/opt/ruby`?  You didn't run `echo $PATH` as root, you ran `echo /opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/‌​games` as root -- not the same thing, and a definite misleading data point.  Yes, you should add `/opt/ruby/bin` to `root`'s `PATH`.

Comment: I installed REE, and it asked for a prefix which I have /opt/ruby.

Comment: I'm on ec2, so I can't login as root, so I thought you meant to write 'sudo echo $PATH' when you said 'and then run echo $PATH as root (via sudo).  So 'sudo echo $PATH' gives me: /opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

Comment: If I'd meant to write `sudo echo $PATH` I would have written that.  I added "(via sudo)" because I was pretty sure that if I hadn't added that, you would have come back with "but I don't have root!".  Also, being on EC2 has nothing to do with whether you can login as root.

Comment: sorry, I'm just not following, furballs are flying in my head :(